# How to access pixel coordinates using queryRenderedFeatures in Mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Good day!

I want to access x,y pixel coordinates of all the feature's in mapbox-gl-js using queryRenderedFeatures method.

When I console log the feature, I can see only the variable "_vectorTileFeature" that contains the pixel coordinates?

I guess that this "_vectorTileFeature" is an internal variable the Mapbox team might be using and the key also might change in the future.

Is there any other way to access them?

Attaching screenshot:
[image]

Any suggestion would be helpful?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @SteveBennett, This is a task I have been assigned to and gather all x,y pixel coordinate's of the feature's queried from "queryRenderedFeatures" or "querySourceFeatures" method.

Comment: I found that all the events callback have direct access to x,y pixel co-ordinates but not found any easy way to access them in the instance members

Comment: "This is a task I have been assigned to and gather all x,y pixel coordinate's of the feature's" - this doesn't really explain what you're trying to achieve. What is the actual goal of this task? Maybe there is a different way to get there?

Answer (score 2):

Use map.**project(lng, lat)** to find the pixel coordinates.